# Dependency property value is not inherited

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I declared a dependency property with `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits`:

```
public static class DesignerItemStyles {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderBackgroundProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "HeaderBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(DesignerItemStyles),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                Brushes.DesignerViewElementHeaderBackground,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));

    /* Below are Get & Set as usual */
}
```

It kind of works, but somehow  not throughout the visual tree. Here is a screenshot showing `ContentPresenter` that inherit value from `HeaderedDesignerItemChrome`:
[image: Node that inherits value]

And now, a screenshot showing content of the `ContentPresenter`, and it does not inherit the value. Nor it is set to something else - it is a default value:
[image: Direct child that does not]

Any idea why?

Comment: if ContentPresenter has a DP call HeaderBackground this would work
other wise this as to be an attached property .

Comment: It is an attached property. I posted the declaration at the top.

Comment: could it be that your doing something inside DesignerItemsPresenter 
maybe some MetaData Override for this property ?

Comment: No, nothing of that sort

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, 

Brushes.DesignerViewElementHeaderBackground == #FFE9ECEE
which is the default . 

and that's what we see in snoop , 

and then somewhere along the way you set #FFADE180 
can you show where it is set ?

Comment: It is set on HeaderedDesignerItemChrome. Set by the trigger when IsMouseOver == True, which is reflected by snoop, which shows Value Source to be TemplateTrigger.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50133/discussion-between-eugene-strizhok-and-eran-otzap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminating one of the two ContentPresenters (visible on both screenshots just above DesignerItemsPresenter) worked for me. I am inclined to believe that was a bug in WPF framework itself.

Answer (score 8):

Using this is not that straight forward since there are some rules that need to be followed to implement property with inheritable values. Here they are:

On parent, dependency property must be defined as attached property. You can still declare property getter/setter, but property must be attached. Here is simple declaration:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InheritedValueProperty =
   DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InheritedValue",
   typeof(int), typeof(MyClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, 
   FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
public static int GetInheritedValue(DependencyObject target)
{
   return (int)target.GetValue(InheritedValueProperty);
}
public static void SetInheritedValue(DependencyObject target, int value)
{
   target.SetValue(InheritedValueProperty, value);
}
public int InheritedValue
{
   get
   {
      return GetTimeSlotDuration(this);
   }
   set
   {
      SetTimeSlotDuration(this, value);
   }
}
```

Child objects would define their instance of the property with inherited value using AddOwner. Following is the code that goes into say MyChildClass sample class:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InheritedValueProperty;
public int InheritedValue
{
   get
   {
      return (int)GetValue(InheritedValueProperty);
   }
   set
   {
      SetValue(InheritedValueProperty, value);
   }
}
static MyChildClass()
{
   InheritedValueProperty = 
       MyClass.InheritedValueProperty.AddOwner(typeof(MyChildClass),
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0,
                   FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
}
```

The global default value is preserved and inheritance still works, if the single argument overload is used...

```
MyClass.InheritedValueProperty.AddOwner(typeof(MyChildClass));
```

Note that property is in child class declared as standard dependency property and that it specifies Inherit in meta-data options.

With setup like this now when MyChildClass in parented to MyClass visually or logically they will share the same property value automatically.

So technically, what you see in the Visual Tree is doing what you told it to do. It set the default value that you told it to and the inherited controls inherit from the value of the parent which is your ContentPresenter

Comment: Could you please clarify, what you mean by "the inherited controls" in the last sentence? Anyway, my question is why ControlPresenter inherits the value while DesignerItemsPresenter does not. Neither of "inherit" in any way from HeaderedDesignerItemChrome, where the value was set.

Comment: Is that right to assume that a control might not inherit value of an inheritable dependency property set somewhere higher in the tree, unless it is added as an owner for that property (a call to AddOwner)?

Comment: @EugeneStrizhok Yes it won't inherit higher from the tree unless it explicitly calls the class in its static constructor and you tell it to inherit the `dependencyproperty` to inherit from the based class. See the `static constructor` in the sample code I gave you.

Comment: But in this case it would have never worked! Between my control and another my control there will likely be another standard or 3rd-party control. Following that logic, they won't inherit the value, and, thus, neither would my control underneath them. I don't get it...

Comment: Anyhow, I tried calling AddOwner. It made no difference.

Comment: @EugeneStrizhok Give me a sample project

Comment: `InheritedValueProperty` is readonly so this doesn't work for me. If I leave it out and access `InheritedValue` in the child property directly - without using `GetValue` and `SetValue` - it works the same.

Comment: Actually, my bad: I forgot to put the assignment in a static constructor. This is absolutely brilliant; works perfectly. Proposed an edit to explain how to inherit the parent default value...